# An 8 hour RPC call using rabbitmq. It sounds crazy but is there anything wrong with it?

Tags: rabbitmq, jruby, rpc, publish-subscribe, amqp

I'm using jruby and java's com.rabbitmq.client to make an rpc call to a worker process through rabbitmq.  The call could take up to 8 hours to complete.  Using RPC seems wrong but since it's basically just a pub/sub I'm wondering if it's actually a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using an exclusive replyto/callback queue. The only problem with this approach is that if the producer goes down, the queue will vanish, and the response will be lost. A better approach maybe to use a DB to log the job's state/response, and fire events on the job's state change, which interested parties may subscribe to. I'd generally avoid coupling in any fashion for such long running jobs.